# How to upgrade from bootstrap V3.2.0 to V5.1.2 - (button collapse does not work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am responsible for SharePoint internet site in my company and this site was built using bootstrap V3.2.0 they want to upgrade this old site to latest version of Bootstrap V5.1.2

**my problem** is that when I updated the file (bootstrab.min.js) to latest version the menu button in mobile view does not work.
In older ver of bootstrap the (.in) class is added to the collapse div While in latest ver it added (.show).

**so how do I upgrade the bootstrap to latest version while keeping my site design same?**
I know that the css file and js file of bootstrap have to be upgraded together and I know there are new api and classes removed from older ver but the problem **how to migrate these changes to my site?
is there a migration document I can follow ? or a way to solve the collapse of the button because it is the only thing that does not work when I updated the file!**

Comment: If you read the official docs you can find all the difference....

Comment: @sfili_81 I know but they are expecting me to solve the issue today and from my point of view this is not a simple issue that can be solved within a day I mean there is like 6000 line from the old ver that I need to compare it with the new one..am I right?

Comment: Yes it's not a little issue... you have to check the difference.....

Comment: Please see [ask]. You'd need to show your code so we have something to talk about.

Comment: The short answer is that you'll have to look at the docs for the components you're using and make the necessary markup changes. There's no miracle cure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Kazushia! Wow, first question in 5 years of being a user :) Big milestone.

> so how do I upgrade the bootstrap to latest version while keeping my site design same

Bootstrap's major versions include some major design changes – alongside major, breaking code changes. I guarantee that "the collapse div" issue you've noted is not the only issue.

That being said, there are migration documents:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

...unfortunately, the v5 migration path is a really long one.

Ultimately, you might be better off accepting the design differences. As @isherwood noted in a comment, there is no miracle cure here.